# array inside function

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop, codeblocks

Create a function to display array.

Comment: `const char* questions[] = { "Question1", "Question2" , … }`

Comment: @A.nonymous if `char*` and `char` is not clear for you, you have to start to learn C basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE_ALLOTED_TO_EACH_QUESTION 100
#define NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS 10

int scoreList[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS]; // This array will contain the individual score for each answers to respective questions
int i;

void Extroversion(int scoreList[]){

        // Let formula for this be E = 20 +(1)___-(3)___+(2)___-(4)___
        int E = 20 + (scoreList[1] + scoreList[2]) - (scoreList[3] + scoreList[4]);
        printf("\nExtroversion is the personality trait of seeking fulfillment from sources outside the self or in community. High scorers tend to be very social while low scorers prefer to work on their projects alone.\nYour score for this trait is: %d\n\n", E);
}

void Agreeableness(int scoreList[]){

        // Let formula for this be A = 14 -(2)___+(5)___-(3)___+(6)___
        int A = 20 + (scoreList[5] + scoreList[6]) - (scoreList[2] + scoreList[3]);
        printf("\nAgreeableness reflects much individuals adjust their behavior to suit others. High scorers are typically polite and like people. Low scorers tend to 'tell it like it is'.\nYour score for this trait is: %d\n\n", A);
}

/*

* Similarily for Conscientiousness, Neuroticism and Openness_to_Experience

*/


int main(){

        const char question[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS][MAX_SIZE_ALLOTED_TO_EACH_QUESTION] = { "1. Am the life of the party.", "2. Feel little concern for others.", "3. Am always prepared.", "4. Get stressed out easily.", "5. Have a rich vocabulary.", "6. Don't talk a lot.", "7. Am interested in people.", "8. Leave my belongings around.", "9. Am relaxed most of the time.", "10. Have difficulty understanding abstract ideas." };

        for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; i++){
                printf("%s :\nYour Score: ", question[i]);
                scanf("%d", &scoreList[i]); // Here each element is storing the value between 0-5 for their corresponsding question
 }

        Extroversion(scoreList);
        Agreeableness(scoreList);
//      Conscientiousness(scoreList);
//      Neuroticism(scoreList);
//      Openness_to_Experience(scoreList);

return 0;
}
```

I think it would be good for you to go through the code once. I have mentioned comments in the code using `//` and `/* */`. Read the comments properly. I have checked the code working for 10 questions on my system, so there would be no error if you complete following the pattern in which i have written. And don't forget to look at the formula. The array index need to be according to the formula in the original pdf you have shared.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &scoreList[i]); // Here each element is storing the value between 0-5 for their corresponsding question`
I don't understand this part. The 0-5 isn't define or declare yet.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will read through your codes and the comments again and again. I cant thank you enough. And if you don't mind, can you please delete the previous answer and the coments? thank you again.

Comment: Either modify the scanf as `scanf("%[1-5]d, scoreList[i] ) ` to take only integers between 1-5 or print to tell user to enter only between 1-5. Both can be good for you.

Comment: Oh, I see. I will use the print then because I have learned that. Thank you.

Comment: I see where my mistake now. I was too focused on char that instead of using int for E, etc.. I used char. Do we need a function definition?

Comment: Function definition (however call it function prototype) won't be needed if you writing the definitions before main function.

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thank you

Comment: Hmm. I think it is still not complete as it does not show what type of personality you are after finishing inputting the scores. Perhaps the return should not be 0?

Comment: It displays each personality trait score. Something more is required?

Comment: Yes, I need to show the result of the final scores for the trait of the person.

Comment: In case you wish to display the actual personality, you will have to read the definition for each personality trait. Check for the final result of the each personality accordingly. For Example: in case of extroversion, if E > 30 then "the person is social" else if <10 "He/She is introvert"

Comment: Why is the `scoreList[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS]` not use? I still can't get the personality type.

Comment: The `scoreList[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS]` is being used..check

Comment: Oh it is being used. But still the function definition is not calling. Is the return type wrong? And how do I make the program not to let user input more than 5 score for each question?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

int scoreList[SIZE];
int i;

int findTotal(int scoreList[SIZE], int inSmall, int inLarge){
        int total =0;
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
        {
                if (scoreList[index]!= inSmall && scoreList[index]!= inLarge)
                total = total + scoreList[index];
        }
        return total;
}
int findLarge(int scoreList[SIZE]){
        int index;
        int largest = scoreList[0];
        for (index=1; index < SIZE; index++)
        {
                if (scoreList[index] > largest)
                largest = scoreList[index];
        }
        return largest;
}
int findSmall(int scoreList[SIZE]){
        int index;
        int smallest = scoreList[0];
        for (index=1; index < SIZE; index++)
        {
                if (scoreList[index] < smallest)
                smallest = scoreList[index];
        }
        return smallest;
}

int main(){

        const char* question[] = { "I don't talk a lot", "I have people around me", "I love nature", "I talk about science", "And bla bla bla" };

        // char question[SIZE][100] = {"I don't talk a lot","why this is good","one two","fourth","fifth"}; // If you don't wish to use pointer, You will have to use a 2D char array that will store the total number of element and second one will store length of each element (here 100)

        for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
                printf("%s :\nYour Score: ", question[i]);
                scanf("%d", &scoreList[i]);
        }

        int smallest = findSmall(scoreList);
        int largest = findLarge(scoreList);
        int total = findTotal(scoreList, smallest, largest);

        printf("smallest: %d, largest: %d, total: %d\n", smallest, largest, total);
return 0;
}
```

I have run it on my system. Working fine!

Comment: @A.nonymous , using the above you can get the list of array containing the individual scores. Now you can use the array accordingly to canculate rest of your requisites. Let me know if you wish to ask something!

Comment: Don't worry if you have not learned about `char*` yet. It's called pointer, a value that stores the address of the location for the actual data that will be stored in it, one of the most useful things if you are going for C programming. It's not anything difficult to learn if you are into regular practice. You can go for tutorials and sessions on pointers on internet.

Comment: For your next query:
`const char* question[] = { "Write anything inside double quotes", "Anything you wish", "Each will be treated as one element", "for the given array questions", "Q5" };`

Comment: I am writing you the code properly. Give me a moment

Comment: No that isn't what I was asking but it is okay.

Comment: I have added a comment below const char* . See the edited answer. you can either use 2D or char* to solve this. I have even explained it.

Comment: but I can't use the pointer because I haven't learn it yet so how do I do that part?

Comment: @A.nonymous Please see I have edited the char* to a 2D char array in the answer. When you use a 2D char array, you don't need to do it using a pointer. I have replaced `const char* question[]` to `char question[SIZE][100]`

Comment: Please concentrate on what you are learning. Simple char array cannot hold value more than one character in single quote. You need other techniques to hold them. Gave you two methods..if you feel it is answering your question, give an acceptance or else study basics of C from online portals! Thanks..

Comment: Okay thank you. I understand your answer and can you help me to see my edited codes and question if you don't mind again?

Comment: `printf("1. I am the life of the party.\t", questionList[0]);` statement makes no sense. If you wish to scan the rating from the user after displaying the question, the correct method is
`printf("1. I am the life of the party.\t");`
`scanf("%d", &scoreList[1])`
By this, every question (which in your case could have been easily done using a loop) gets a respective entry for score in `scoreList` array. Now using this scoreList array you can do all sort of other calculations that you wish.

Comment: You have all your questions in a different array. All your scores respectively in another array. So you have scores seperately for all your questions. You can do your calculations using them.

Comment: But I need to assign them to each question to do the calculation. Why is it that you corrected it to `scanf("%d", &scoreList[1]` instead of `&scoreList[SIZE]`? they are not different, they are the subsets of my array.

Comment: Because in case of `&scoreList[SIZE]` `SIZE` which is constant `(=5)` is in a way overwriting the value at `scoreList[5]` at each iteration.

Comment: How do I do the image part? How do I assign them?

Comment: @A.nonymous you are trying to hard-code everything. This is not the correct way to approach. You need to fully edit your question once again as it has been complicated after all your edits. If possible directly copy paste the problem statement. I will see if I can help in your project by giving you the exact code for it. If then you have doubts in the code, ask specific questions and I will be happy to answer.

Comment: What is hard-code? Please help me I cannot afford to fail my assignment. And I have to submit it soon. And my question is not complicated.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question but first can we delete all our coments and start again otherwise this will be a comment section. Also can you delete your prevous answer and I'll ask you specific questions and we start from there.

Comment: Ok then clear out the following for me..1) You have to create a function to display the stored 50 questions, that means you must be given as array of 50 questions or is it that you have to make it? 2) Each question's value that user enters have to be stored where? 3) Where is the picture coming in the question?

Comment: 1) I am already given an array of 50 questions so I do not need to create them. 2) I think store in array as mentioned in the question 3) the picture comes from the bigfivepersonalitytest file 4) And the file has nothing much besides the 50 questions with the picture i posted

Comment: cool. Lastly just tell me how is your question array defined, is it `const char* question` or `char question [] []` or something else?

Comment: send me big five personality test.pdf on ashishkrbit@gmail.com

Comment: This is where I don't get it too. I do not know which way to define my question array but I think it is something else.

Comment: Okay I have sent you

Comment: Now hold on for a few minutes!

Comment: Okay take your time to understand.

Comment: Ok so you have to convert this into a C program that will be able to calculate and print the specific traits according to the formula mentioned. I am right?

Comment: Yes. I have to make it into a personality test program using function and array with the formula given.

Comment: CodeBlocks is nothing but an editor. Don't worry about that. Now, What I can do is, I will give you a code for 10 questions (as I won't be able to manually write all of them here, as required). Expand it to your 50 question length in similar fashion. I will try making it as simple as possible.

Comment: Yup, you can use any editor haha. Okay that would be cool! I will then expand it from your code.